# Rails 3 Routes Multiple Params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

This may be a basic question, and I'm not even sure if it's possible, but here goes.

If I have a event model which is composed of events, and the URLs are /events to see all, and /events/:id to see an individual event... Can I also do something like /events/:status to redirect to the index controller and show say, previous, inactive events and so on based on what that status is, but also preserve the /events/:id functionality?

So basically:

/events/17 would bring me to the 17th event created and /events/previous would bring me to a listing of all events that have come and gone.

Is this possible? if so, how would I setup the routes?

I tried:

```
match "/events/:status" => "events#index"

resources :events
```

but that just overrides the :id one, so I can no longer get to an individual event. I'm still learning all of the terminology of rails, so my searching abilities are a little limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
match "/events/previous" => "events#index", :defaults => { :status => 'previous' }
```

This assumes your status is of limit number, so you could define them all each in online manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could use segment key constraints to set up the routes.

For example,

```
match "/events/:id" => "events#show", :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ }

match "/events/:status" => "events#index", :constraints => { :status => /\w+/ }
```

In this case `/events/17` would route to the show action in the Events controller while `/events/previous` would route to the index action.

You could set your status constraints to be more specific if you want, but I think this should work.

Comment: While this would be great, I then would have to spell out each of the some other actions like, "new" that I didn't previously have to. I guess it's kind of a toss up.